# How to use a deleted app name in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I created an app in iTunes Connect and then later deleted that app before uploading the app to the store.

When I try to create another app with the same name (even though it is now deleted), I get an alert from iTunes Connect saying: The App Name you entered has already been used.

Is there anyway to use the old app name?

Comment: iTunes should have specifically warned you that if you delete the app you can never use the name again yourself.

Comment: That's not really true. If it expires (you don't upload it within so many days), it gets deleted and the name is freed. So, I imagine if you deleted it, it would also be available unless someone else used it. Contact Apple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: I have removed my app and create new app with the same name of removed app ,, they approved without any issues

Answer (score 9):

From the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW37):

> **Important**: If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.

So no, you can't reuse the app name.

Comment: link is not working. can you have another or new link ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha It's updated.

Comment: as per the new updated docs, app name is removed. only sku is there. i think it is possible now.

Answer (score 6):

I have spoken with Apple Developer support about this for a similar issue, and they actually made an exception and freed the name up for me.  In my case, I had accidentally allowed a name to expire, and wanted to use it again over a year later.

The kind folks at Apple had to confirm that the name was not in use, and that they did not think I was "squatting" the name, but once they did that, they released it back to me.

It did require a special procedure of some sort on their end, and the case had to be escalated to a manager, but I bet if you call them (try [this number](http://gethuman.com/phone-number/Apple-Developer-Support/)) they might be able to help you out.

Comment: This seems like the only solution, you actually have to mention that you have some sort of copyright on your name for them to proceed and open up a case.

Answer (score 2):

Change your language from English us to English uk for example, get your name back to what you want, save. go back to app change default language on fields to new language and you are good to go.

Comment: You can create an app with UK default language, but then you'll get the same error when you'll try to enter app name for US version, so this is hardly ever a solution